# How to select data from datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datatable.select

I am little bit stuck here .. I have a datatable as _

```
Dim dtPupil As New DataTable

dtPupil.Columns.Add("PupilId", GetType(Integer))
dtPupil.Columns.Add("Forename", GetType(String))
dtPupil.Columns.Add("Surname", GetType(String))
```

I made a select (assuming names combination will be unique)

```
Dim strQuery As String = "Forename ='" & forename & "' and Surname = '" & surname & "'"
Dim dr As DataRow()
dr = dTablePupil.Select(strQuery)
```

I wanna have `PupilId` as an Integer of the row that match, so

```
Dim PupilID As Integer = ??????????
```

What do I need to write here? There will only be 1 row returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly check the length of `DataRow` array,

```
IF dr.Length<>0 Then
  PupilID= CType(dr(0)("PupilId"),Integer)
End If
```

Comment: it's great .. i will accept as an answer .. i am told to wait 3 minutes .. thanks so much .. it works