# How to retrieve data from two rows of a data table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to retrieve data from two row of a data table.

Suppose I have three columns.

```
Column 1      Column 2    column 3
1              14          16
2              15          17
```

I want to retrieve data from row 1 and row 2 so that I can add data  as (15 +16)

Comment: Show what you have already done.

Comment: Check out >[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412466/how-to-select-data-from-datatable#9412532)<

Comment: `Dim sum = datatable.AsEnumerable().Take(2).Select(row => row.Field(Of Integer)("Column1) + row.Field(Of Integer)("Column2) + row.Field(Of Integer)("Column3)).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()`

Comment: When you say data table, do you mean System.Data.DataTable or a table in a database? If your data is still in a database you need to let us know which one.

Comment: I am using access database. I mean access database.